# How can I write the number set of positive rationals in LaTeX2e?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

[image: how to do this?] How to write this in latex2e, the set of all rational numbers.

Comment: `$Q^{+}$`......

Comment: @HarishKumar - why the restriction to the positive rationals?

Comment: @Mico: I just reproduced the picture as a direction :)

Comment: @Mico I need it.

Comment: I usually write `$\mathds{Q}^{+}$` (needs `\usepackage{dsfont}`)

Comment: People usually use double struck letters for number sets so for example `\mathbb{Q}` from amsmath (amsfonts) package

Comment: When not double struck letters – which is a modern way of writing, you can use roman boldface as in Bourbaki's treatise: $\mathbf{Q}^{+}$. Or to look more closely  like the image: $\mathcal{Q}^{+}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like some reference:

In DIN EN ISO 80000-2 (draft) the preferred writing for number sets is bold upright (`$\mathbf{Q}$`). As an remark, the possibilities seen from @karlkoeller (`$\mathds{Q}$`) is shown first and than the one from @David Carlisle (`$\mathbb{Q}$`).

In the older DIN 1302 `$\mathds{Q}$` is shown first and `$\mathbf{Q}$` as coequal choice.

In both standards, the writing for "only positives" is marked as `_{>0}` and not the plus sign.

Here are all versions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont} % for \mathds
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for \mathbb
\begin{document}
DIN EN ISO 80000-2:

$\mathbf{Q}_{>0} \vee \mathds{Q}_{>0} \vee \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$

DIN 1302:

$\mathds{Q}_{>0} \vee \mathbf{Q}_{>0}$

your version:

$\mathbf{Q}^{+} \vee \mathds{Q}^{+}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

nb: I would not use italic symbols here, as they should be used for variables. A number set is kind of a fixed thing and thus no variable.